# Getting to the GRUB menu using IPMI on a supermicro server

Tags: grub, bootloader, ipmi

I have supermicro server running Grub 2.02 BETA 2.  I kind of inherited this box, so I am kind approaching things gingerly.  The box supports ONIE and I want to install a new image, but the first thing I would like to do is to get to the Grub menu.

I think it is worth mentioning that I am accessing the console via IPMI.  For long story short, I have tried holding down the shift key when the Grub Loading message appears.  I have tried hitting C.  ESC, and Spacebar and can't get the menu to appear.

Some more background, It turns out that there is no /etc/default/grub file, but there is a /grub/grub.cfg

I was able to go into the /grub/grub.cfg and change the timeout=5 to timeout=30 and it does affect the time that the message is displayed.

I started wondering if I could be dealing with some artifact of how the supermicro IPMI handles a held down Shift key?

If anyone has any ideas on how to force the Grub menu to appear using the .cfg, I think that would at least get me going, but solving the case of the menu not appearing based on keystroke would work as well.